# Parse Installation not getting DeviceToken

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, push, android-notifications

I am trying to use parse for push notification in android, I am registering parse in the Application class like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, "***************", "***************");
}
```

I am subscribing to push like this in the main activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {


                                if (e == null) {
                                    String deviceToken = (String) ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");
                                    Log.e("MainActivity", "device toekn " + deviceToken);

                                } else {
                                    Log.e("MainActivity", "failed to subscribe for push " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        });

            } else {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

And here is my manifest section the apply to parse:

```
  <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.****" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

however, device token returns null most of the times and the device has no device token in the parse dashboard, therefor, my device is not getting the push notifications.

The odd part is that sometimes it does work, i do get deviceToken and the installation object does get the push, has anyone encountered this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was eventually solved, a simple mistake in the Application name in the  tag of the manifest in the  tag.
since the code i posted here was "com.***" no one could have helped, i apologize.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem and i solved it by modifying my **AndroidManifest** file.

It appears that you can configure parse to either use "**Parse Push Network**" or **GCM (Google Cloud Message)**.

Parse uses its own push network for apps that want to avoid a dependency on the Google Play Store, and for devices (like Kindles) which do not have Play Store support.
Thus it is important to set the below in other to use GCM.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
 <permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
   android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Replace YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME in the declarations above with your application's package name. Also, make sure that com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver and com.parse.PushService are declared as children of the  element:

This worked for me, it might as well work for you.

[Read this to get a full understanding](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/PushService.html)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using version 1.9.3. In version 1.9.4 they have fixed the problem. Check the [release notes](https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads).

Comment: I have seen this issue and tried it,  i am not using 1.9.3 i am using 1.9.4, this issue still perssists

Comment: @ZivKesten did you get the solution for this problem.. I am facing the same with 1.10.2

Comment: My issue was a simple mistake in the category name in the manifest.
 <category android:name="com.****" />
inside the intent receiver.
unfortunately, no real solution here.

Answer (score 1):

It could be useful to set parse logging to verbose to help debug further:

```
Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
```

With that I noticed that I was using the wrong "sender_id" in my manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
        android:value="id:123456789"/>
```

I'm using my own GCM which your not doing here...but LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE might help others debug this.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you saving the installation if you're not adding anything to it? ParseSDK does that for you already.

You must pass a valid "channel" parameter into subscribeInBackground:
This is the channel that parse uses to push with; without it you won't get any pushes at all.
https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePush.html#subscribeInBackground(java.lang.String,%20com.parse.SaveCallback)

In addition make sure you've added the needed tag in your manifest for parse push to work properly -  and the needed  just like it explained here:

https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications-receiving-pushes

Comment: It is to my understanding that if i put " in the channel parameter, this means that this app is registering for all channels. I feel like i must emphasize the fact that this code does work from time to time, i just don't know why and why not.

Comment: From "time to time" sounds like a race condition you're having.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "race condition" could you explain please?